# What does this compiler warning mean? "had text segment at different address"

Tags: compiler-warnings, cross-compiling, gcc-warning, precompiled-headers

I'm cross compiling a project on a Mac running Lion, using GCC for an ARM target. I'm using precompiled headers and getting this warning for every object that compiles against my PCH:

> cc1plus: warning: /yada/yada/yada_afx.hpp.gch: had text segment at different address [enabled by default]

It doesn't seem to stop the program from running but I'm worried it could be causing or contributing to a performance issue. What does the warning mean and should I be worried?

BTW, here's an example of the command that cmake is compiling with (with some long paths removed):

```
/opt/local/bin/arm-linux-uclibc-g++ -DBOOST_PARAMETER_MAX_ARITY=16 \
-DBOOST_MPL_LIMIT_STRING_SIZE=80 -Wno-multichar -g -I/lots/of/include/dirs \
-include yada_afx.hpp -Winvalid-pch -o MySource.cpp.o -c MySource.cpp
```

Comment: Any luck with this? The same issue has been giving me a headache for the past week.